# Unable to see nodes' data on Grafana dashboard

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I have installed Prometheus and Grafana on my Ubuntu. I have added node exporter to scrape metrics. In the Grafana, I added Prometheus as my data source. It got added successfully. However, when I import Node Exporter Dashboard, I do not get any data. What can be the issue?
Here is my Prometheus Job configuration.

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 10s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus_metrics'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'node_exporter_metrics'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100', '192.168.10.42:9100']
```

Here is the grafana log output.

```
level=error msg="Internal server error" error="[plugin.downstreamError] failed to query data: received empty response from prometheus"
```

[Grafana dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbJ0e.png)

Comment: Could you please update the question with the Prometheus job configuration? Do you get metrics on the Prometheus?

Comment: @Andromeda Yes I am getting the metrics of my nodes on prometheus.

Comment: Does `curl localhost:9100` return the node's metrics?

Comment: yes it returns node's metrics. I just went ahead with another dashboard. This time I used Linux memory dashboard. It is working and I can see the output in grafana. However, no other dashboard is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus are change names of labels of Node Exporter metrics.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).